# Put horizontal images inside a script in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new in HTML and i'm having problems to align my images horizontally, actually they are aligning vertically. I can do this in HTMl, but when I add the script everything becames vertically.Here is my script, hope you can help me. I just posted an example of one of the four variables to be for simple for you.

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="medium-0 columns-5">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="sorteo.jpg" style="width:1930px;height:350px;">
<div class="row small-up-4">
<div class="column row">
    <p id="sensor1"> </p>
    <p id="sensor2"> </p>
    <p id="sensor3"> </p>
    <p id="sensor4"> </p>
<script>

    var sensor4 = 0;

if (sensor4==1){
    document.getElementById("sensor4").innerHTML = '<div class="medium-6 columns"> <img class="thumbnail"  src="proximidad.jpg" style="width:250px;height:100px;"> </div>';
    } else {
    document.getElementById("sensor4").innerHTML = '<div class="medium-6 columns"> <img class="thumbnail"  src="azul.jpg" style="width:250px;height:100px;"> </div>';
    }       
</script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[This is how I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yNTE.png)

```js
 var sensor1 = 1;
 
 if (sensor1==1){
  document.getElementById("sensor1").innerHTML = '<img src="motor.jpg" style="width:250px;height:100px;">';
  } else {
  document.getElementById("sensor1").innerHTML = '<img src="azul.jpg" style="width:250px;height:100px;">';
  }
 
 var sensor2 = 0;
 
 if (sensor2==1){
  document.getElementById("sensor2").innerHTML = '<img class="thumbnail" align="center" src="piston.jpg" style="width:250px;height:100px;">';
  } else {
  document.getElementById("sensor2").innerHTML = '<div class="column"> <img class="thumbnail"  src="azul.jpg" style="width:250px;height:100px;"> </div>';
  }
  
 var sensor3 = 1;
 
 if (sensor3==1){
  document.getElementById("sensor3").innerHTML = '<div class="medium-6 columns"> <img class="thumbnail"  src="retro.jpg" style="width:250px;height:100px;"> </div>';
  } else {
  document.getElementById("sensor3").innerHTML = '<div class="medium-6 columns"> <img class="thumbnail"  src="azul.jpg" style="width:250px;height:100px;"> </div>';
  }

  var sensor4 = 0;
 
 if (sensor4==1){
  document.getElementById("sensor4").innerHTML = '<div class="medium-6 columns"> <img class="thumbnail"  src="proximidad.jpg" style="width:250px;height:100px;"> </div>';
  } else {
  document.getElementById("sensor4").innerHTML = '<div class="medium-6 columns"> <img class="thumbnail"  src="azul.jpg" style="width:250px;height:100px;"> </div>';
  }
```

```html
    <div class="row">
      <div class="medium-0 columns-5">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="sorteo.jpg" style="width:1930px;height:350px;">
 <div class="row small-up-4">
 <div class="column">
  <p id="sensor1"> </p>
  <p id="sensor2"> </p>
  <p id="sensor3"> </p>
  <p id="sensor4"> </p>
```

[this is how it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j22W.png)

Comment: Hi, post your CSS, too, so that we have a working demo. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Hello, I downloaded this as a framework from internet. The CSS is really long almost 4000 lines, should I post it?

Comment: Post the relevant section of CSS. Classes that effect image layout, etc.

Comment: .thumbnail {
    border: 4px solid #fefefe;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(10,10,10,.2);
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    transition: box-shadow .2s ease-out;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem
}

.thumbnail:focus,.thumbnail:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(33,153,232,.5)
}

Comment: Can you use JS Fiddle or something similar so that we can see clearly, please.

Comment: Hello Sankarsh I just did that, I'm sorry I'm really new to this

Comment: I still can't figure out what is different from your goal and your current situation. Also for tagging people use @Santiago. It sends a message to their inbox.

Comment: Ok thanks! @SankarshMakam 
My goal is to have all the small four images horizontally, and right now the four images are vertically. In the link "this is how I want to look like" show which is my goal and in the link "this is how it looks right now" shows my current situation.

Comment: It should be noted that your Javascript is creating invalid HTML. Only [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) is allowed to be inside of a `p` tag. `div` elements are not permitted as children of paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know about CSS : display: inline-block 
or float: left;
or display: flex;

**Note :** test it on your monitor... i use display: inline-block... so the content automatically falldown when the window not enough space. And that is we called "Responsive Website" after adding some meta.

```js
function preLoad(){
 var sensor1 = 1;
 if (sensor1==1){
  document.getElementById("sensor1").innerHTML = '<img src="motor.jpg" style="width:250px;height:100px;">';
 }else{
  document.getElementById("sensor1").innerHTML = '<img src="azul.jpg" style="width:250px;height:100px;">';
 }

 var sensor2 = 0;
 if (sensor2==1){
  document.getElementById("sensor2").innerHTML = '<img class="thumbnail" align="center" src="piston.jpg" style="width:250px;height:100px;">';
 }else{
  document.getElementById("sensor2").innerHTML = '<div class="column"> <img class="thumbnail"  src="azul.jpg" style="width:250px;height:100px;"> </div>';
 }

 var sensor3 = 1;
 if (sensor3==1){
  document.getElementById("sensor3").innerHTML = '<div class="medium-6 columns"> <img class="thumbnail"  src="retro.jpg" style="width:250px;height:100px;"> </div>';
 }else{
  document.getElementById("sensor3").innerHTML = '<div class="medium-6 columns"> <img class="thumbnail"  src="azul.jpg" style="width:250px;height:100px;"> </div>';
 }

 var sensor4 = 0;
 if (sensor4==1){
  document.getElementById("sensor4").innerHTML = '<div class="medium-6 columns"> <img class="thumbnail"  src="proximidad.jpg" style="width:250px;height:100px;"> </div>';
 }else{
  document.getElementById("sensor4").innerHTML = '<div class="medium-6 columns"> <img class="thumbnail"  src="azul.jpg" style="width:250px;height:100px;"> </div>';
 }
}
```

```css
.sensorContent{
 text-align: center;
 }
.sensorContent p{
  display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<body onload="preLoad();">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="medium-0 columns-5">
   <img class="thumbnail" src="sorteo.jpg" style="width:1930px;height:350px;">
   <div class="row small-up-4">
    <div class="column row sensorContent">
     <p id="sensor1"></p>
     <p id="sensor2"></p>
     <p id="sensor3"></p>
     <p id="sensor4"></p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello @JackRose thank you very much for your help! I just want to know where did you put this part?
.sensorContent{
 text-align: center;
 }
.sensorContent p{
  display: inline-block;
 }

Did you put it in the CSS or in the script of java or where?

Comment: that is stylesheet/css

so you can add it on .html / .php file

<style>
.sensorContent{
 text-align: center;
 }
.sensorContent p{
  display: inline-block;
 }
</style>

or create new file like "myCustomStyle.css" and add the stylesheet.
but you need to call the stylesheet with
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/folder/folder/folder/myCustomStyle.css" />